# Handling and running multiple ViewControllers in the same method

Tags: ios, view, viewcontroller

I have a MainViewController which has a button init. On the button click a pictures starts animating, then I create a new instance of a different ViewController that runs a web request and extracts some info and push it in front. I wish the image to be animating while the middle view controller is running. Finally once the MiddleViewController is done, in the same button method I switch to a 3rd ViewController. As it is expected I get the following error:

```
    Warning: Attempt to present <ThirdViewController: 0x962b470> on <MainViewController: 0x986c200> while a presentation is in progress!
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions
```

How could I fix this? I prefer not to remove the middle ViewController and integrate its code in the MainViewController.

```
-(void)singleTapping:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{

    UIImage *rot1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic1.png"];
    UIImage *rot2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic2.png"];
    UIImage *rot3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic3.png"];
    UIImage *rot4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic4.png"];

    self.scanclickedimage.animationImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:rot1, rot2, rot3, rot4, nil];
    self.scanclickedimage.animationDuration = 0.6f;
    self.scanclickedimage.animationRepeatCount = HUGE_VALF;

    [self.scanclickedimage startAnimating];


    if (nextString == NULL || [nextString isEqualToString:@""]) {

        NSLog(@"Initializing MiddleViewController");
        MiddleViewController * middleViewController = [[MiddleViewController alloc] init];
        middleViewController.delegate = self;

        [self presentViewController:middleViewController animated:YES completion:nil];



    } else {
        ProductWebRequest *request = [[ProductWebRequest alloc] init];
        [request sendWebRequest:nextString];
    }






    NSString * storyboardName = @"MainStoryboard";
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
    UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ThirdViewController"];
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];




}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, this error appears when you present / push more than 2 viewcontroller at the same time (or very fast), and the "animated" option is set to "YES".

Try to set animated to "NO" like this:

```
[self presentViewController:middleViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Or do something like this:

```
[self presentViewController:middleViewController animated:YES completion:{
   [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];      
}];
```

You have to update your code to do this. Try to put all the stuff in a separated method like this:

```
-(void)singleTapping:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{

    UIImage *rot1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic1.png"];
    UIImage *rot2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic2.png"];
    UIImage *rot3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic3.png"];
    UIImage *rot4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic4.png"];

    self.scanclickedimage.animationImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:rot1, rot2, rot3, rot4, nil];
    self.scanclickedimage.animationDuration = 0.6f;
    self.scanclickedimage.animationRepeatCount = HUGE_VALF;

    [self.scanclickedimage startAnimating];


    if (nextString == NULL || [nextString isEqualToString:@""]) {

        NSLog(@"Initializing MiddleViewController");
        MiddleViewController * middleViewController = [[MiddleViewController alloc] init];
        middleViewController.delegate = self;

        [self presentViewController:middleViewController animated:YES completion:^{
            [self launchTest];
        }];

    } else {
        ProductWebRequest *request = [[ProductWebRequest alloc] init];
        [request sendWebRequest:nextString];
        [self launchTest];

    }
}

- (void)launchTest {

    NSString * storyboardName = @"MainStoryboard";
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
    UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ThirdViewController"];
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately I have tried it and it does not fix the issue

Comment: The second part of the code provides an error of "Expected Expression"

Comment: The "Expected Expression" error or "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions" ?

Comment: The unbalanced one. I updated the error. Maybe it is cause of the animated image? How could I set it to animate only while the ProductWebRequest is running?

Comment: I've noticed you use Storyboard... You should present your middleViewController using a Segue in Storyboard. Just connect the segue, choose the type of present you want and iOS do the trick. Thank, in the viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear method in MiddleViewController, present programmatically the other one.

Comment: My button is programmatically made. Should I use a segue linking the View Controllers? MainViewController -> MiddleViewController -> ThirdViewController. But I don't want the MiddleViewController to be displayed separately, but as a subview of the MainViewController

Comment: As you're using a Storyboard, I suggest to you to do all you can do in it. It's very useful and easy to use, a lot of thing is managed by the Storyboard / iOS. Simply, drag and drop your button in your VC. Then, simply select your button and connect them to the VC you want, and choose "Present Modal View" for the type of presentation you want (or another one if you want). Finally, you can launch your ThirdViewController after the MiddleViewController is appeared.

Comment: My button is an image view so I cannot insert it in the storyboard. If I connect a segue to the MiddleVC (I want it to run on the mainVC as a subview), then the mainVC will disappear and the MiddleVC will come up. I need to go directly from MainVC to ThirdVC and have the MiddleVC ran on the background, while the MainVC is displayed and when it is done to transition to the ThirdVC.

Comment: You can add a UIButton, and the background image of this button is your image in the imageView ;)